# Adjust Grid Size according to the content

Tags: c#, wpf, grid-layout

How can i define Grid size so that it can increase and decrease according to the TextBlock Content in wpf?

Comment: Refer this link : http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html

Comment: Show us what you've tried, first

Answer (score 0):

Hey the following code snippet sets the `SizeToContent` to WidthAndHeight.

```
    <Window x:Class="WindowSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="WPF Window Sample"
    Width="300" Height="200" Left="500" Top="500"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" >
```